# From which thread is dealloc called under ARC?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, automatic-ref-counting

I always assumed that under ARC `dealloc` is always called from the same thread you initially used to create the object, but I am not really sure about this and I couldn't find any reference to this in Apple's official documentation. Is this true? or is called from the thread where the last reference was held?

**Edit:**
I understand ARC will automatically add `retain` and `release` calls, does this mean that `dealloc` will be executed on the same thread where the last `release` was called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ARC does not change any semantics with regard to on which thread memory management will happen.

Comment: I understand, but can you elaborate a little more? I understand ARC will automatically add retain/release calls, does this mean that the `dealloc` method will perform from the last thread where `release` was called?

Comment: @Raspu, right. It will be called in last `release` where reference count reaches zero.

Comment: @Cy-4AH Great thanks!

Comment: In reality, if you do stuff in dealloc that cares about which thread it is running on, then this is quite dubious.

Comment: @gnasher729 Yeah, I was just curious about this after I saw a bug in a code (that I didn't write).